# A special restriction of a non-constant continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, connectedness

Let $f\colon U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a non-constant continuous function from an open [$n$-dimensional interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Multi-dimensional_intervals) to $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $f$ hits zero. Show that there is a open subinterval $U' \subseteq U$ such as that:

1. The restriction of $f$ to $U'$ is non-constant;
2. $f(U')$ does not contain zero.

I've found how to prove this in two ways, one for the case $n = 1$ using *suprema* and *infima*, and one using this more general statement from general topology:

> Let $U$ be a connected open subset of a connected space $X$ and let $f\colon U\to Y$ be a continuous function from $U$ to a Hausdorff space $Y$. If $f$ is non-constant and $y$ is in the image of $f$, then there is a connected open subset $U' \subseteq U$ such as that $f\colon U' \to Y$ is non-constant and does not hit $y$.

This statement has a relatively small proof. Although, I'm interested in a proof for arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that does not resort to concepts of abstract topology, more like the proof for $n = 1$. I've tried to generalize it, but I don't think I can simply take arbitrary products of subintervals of $U$ like it's done in $n = 1$.

---

**The proof for $n = 1$**

Let $U = (a_0, b_0)$ and let $$a_1 = \inf\{x \in U | f(x) \neq 0\}$$ $$b_1 = \inf\{x \in (a_1, b_0) | f(x) = 0\}$$

We have $a_1 < b_1$ because if they were equal this would mean that we would have two sequences $\lim x_i = \lim y_i = a_1$ with $\lim f(x_i) = 0$ and $\lim f(y_i) \neq 0$. Clearly $(a_1, b_1) \subseteq (a_0, b_0)$. Now, take any sequence $\{x_i\}$ in $(a_1, b_1)$ converging to $b_1$. Then, the sequence $\{f(x_i)\}$ is a sequence of nonzero terms converging to zero, so $f$ is not constant on $(a_1, b_1) = U'$.

---

**The general topology proof**

Take $U'$ to be any connected component of the open $f^{-1}(Y - \{y\})$. Clearly $U'$ is a connected open subset of $X$ (it is open in the open subset $U$) whose image does not contain $y$. Now, $U'$ is not closed in $U$ (because it is a proper open subset of a connected $U$). This means that $U'$ has a cluster point $x \in U - U' = f^{-1}(y)$. Let $\{x_i\}_{i \in I}$ be any sequence converging to $x$. Then $f(x_i)$ converges to $y$ by values different than $y$. Given that $Y$ is Hausdorff, $f(x_i)$ cannot be constant (for the limit is unique and every constant is the limit of itself).

Comment: Why are you interested in avoiding topology? One could argue that it's made for these types of questions.

Comment: @TonyS.F. I personally prefer the topological proof too, but for colleagues in other areas that only study multivariate real calculus without delving into topology, seems too much to ask of them to understand this machinery only to proof this rather intuitive result. I've stumbled upon this while trying to apply the mean value inequality to composites of certain functions derivable everywhere except at zero, and trying to show that generally we can avoid that problematic point by restricting the domain.